# Need to merge virtual disk into one on a dell server, anyone know a better way?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid

**Background Info:**

Raid controler is: PERC 6/i 
Raid 1
3 virtual drives C:58GB, E:97GB, and F:772GB
I need to combine C and E
C is windows install and there is no data on E

---

The way I was going to do this was use acronis to image drive C and F then go to the raid utility and delete all of the virtual disk. Make two new virtual disk with the correct sizes and then restore the images on the new virtual disk. Is this the best / fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Imaging the current drives and re-building the RAID array would likely be the easiest solution.

You can likely achieve what you want some third party software like PartitionMagic, but unless you already have a license for something like that it's much more cost-effective to just do what you planned on doing.

Comment: Since the drives are virtual drives [built in the raid utility] wouldn't the partitioning software just see 3 "physical drives" thus not able to combine the drives?

Comment: Quite possibly, yes.